# Jest mock function is called but expect.toHaveBeenCalled() fails

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I know that there are already questions about this but I can't find a definite answer. I am using SvelteKit and I tried to mock `$app/navigation` likes this in setup file.

```js
jest.mock('$app/navigation', () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        goto: jest.fn().mockImplementation((target) => console.log(target))
    };
});
```

I test a component that call `goto`. It is indeed called because there is a `console.log` call in the test output. When I tried to test it with `expect(goto).toHaveBeenCalled()`, it fails.

```js
    // SvelteKit
    import * as navigations from '$app/navigation';
    it('show error when account does not exists', async () => {
        // render is in before Each
        await fireEvent.change(screen.getByLabelText('Email'), {
            target: { value: 'example@email.com' }
        });
        await fireEvent.change(screen.getByLabelText('Password'), {
            target: { value: 'B@adPass0rd' }
        });
        await fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));
        // There is no problem. It should redirect.
        expect(navigations.goto).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Output

```
 console.log
    /success

      at log (jest-setup.js:6:58)

 FAIL  src/lib/routes-tests/login.test.js
  Login
    ✕ show error when account does not exists (23 ms)

  ● Login › show error when account does not exists

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      24 |              await fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));
      25 |              // expect(screen.queryByText('Account does not exist')).not.toBeNull();
    > 26 |              expect(navigations.goto).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                                       ^
      27 |      });
      28 | });
      29 |

      at toHaveBeenCalled (src/lib/routes-tests/login.test.js:26:28)
      at tryCatch (src/lib/routes-tests/login.test.js:23:2404)
      at Generator._invoke (src/lib/routes-tests/login.test.js:23:1964)
      at Generator.next (src/lib/routes-tests/login.test.js:23:3255)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (src/lib/routes-tests/login.test.js:25:103)
      at _next (src/lib/routes-tests/login.test.js:27:194)
```

Comment: The mock and the test should be in the same file. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas No, the problem is from another method. I called the function in `async` but did not call `waitFor`.

Comment: Could you share your jest config? I'm trying to use Jest with SvelteKit but I get "goto is not a function" error.

Answer (score 11):

It turns out that I called `goto` in `async` function. I must use `waitFor` to expect the change.

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(navigations.goto).toHaveBeenCalled())
```

Comment: This saved my day! Didn't realize the main function "`execute`" used an `await op1()` inside it so my spy of the mocked op1 function passed just fine by the next line, `expect(spyOp2)` that happens after op1 was `await`ed was saying "received function calls: `0`". Just adding an `await` in front of `execute` did the trick.